# Efficiently sorting a numpy array in descending order?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I am surprised this specific question hasn't been asked before, but I really didn't find it on SO nor on the documentation of `np.sort`.

Say I have a random numpy array holding integers, e.g:

```
> temp = np.random.randint(1,10, 10)    
> temp
array([2, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 7, 6, 4, 4])
```

If I sort it, I get ascending order by default:

```
> np.sort(temp)
array([2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7])
```

but I want the solution to be sorted in **descending** order.

Now, I know I can always do:

```
reverse_order = np.sort(temp)[::-1]
```

but is this last statement **efficient**? Doesn't it create a copy in ascending order, and then reverses this copy to get the result in reversed order? If this is indeed the case, is there an efficient alternative? It doesn't look like `np.sort` accepts parameters to change the sign of the comparisons in the sort operation to get things in reverse order.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

`temp[::-1].sort()` sorts the array in place, whereas `np.sort(temp)[::-1]` creates a new array.

```
In [25]: temp = np.random.randint(1,10, 10)

In [26]: temp
Out[26]: array([5, 2, 7, 4, 4, 2, 8, 6, 4, 4])

In [27]: id(temp)
Out[27]: 139962713524944

In [28]: temp[::-1].sort()

In [29]: temp
Out[29]: array([8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2])

In [30]: id(temp)
Out[30]: 139962713524944
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does `temp[::-1].sort()` know that it has to sort in reverse order?? The way I read it is: reverse the original array, and then sort it (in ascending order). Why would reversing the original array (coming in a random order) and then sorting it in ascending order return the array in reversing order?

Comment: Is this behaviour documented, as it is pretty unintuitive.

Comment: Not that I have seen but `[::-1]` is often used with `argsort`

Comment: This looks like it works because the `[::-1]` simply tells numpy to iterate over the array backwards, rather than actually reordering the array. So when the in-place sort happens, it actually sorts in ascending order and moves bits around, but leaves the backwards-iteration part untouched.

Comment: How does `[::-1]` tell that to numpy? How is numpy aware of the indexing that is applied on the object, before it is called? isn't `temp[::-1]` resolved before calling `.sort()`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think the main concern here is memory (creating copies) not running time.

Comment: With `a=np.array((...))` the idiom `a[::-1]` does not reverse anything, it's just a _new view_ on the same data, more specifically a mirror view. The method `a[::-1].sort()` **operates on the mirrored image**, implying that when `sort` moves _left_ a smaller item in its mirrored image, in reality it is moving it to the _right_ in the real memory block of the `a` array.  The mirrored view is sorted in ascending order, the real data is sorted in descending order. Try it at home by yourself, with some different coins and a mirror!

Comment: This really ought to be added as a readable parameter, like `np.sort(temp,order='descending')` rather than requiring these kinds of hacks

Comment: I share @Echelon's feelings here. I'd really like to know the **official** stand of numpy dev on whether this can be counted upon as guaranteed behavior, and if so, on what conceptual grounds is it justified.

Comment: @gboffi For that matter, the statement *"`np.sort(temp)[::-1]` creates a new array"* isn't really accurate either...

Answer (score 172):

```
>>> a=np.array([5, 2, 7, 4, 4, 2, 8, 6, 4, 4])

>>> np.sort(a)
array([2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

>>> -np.sort(-a)
array([8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Best answer -- short and sweet, and no knowledge of the `axis` to which `np.sort` was applied is necessary.

Comment: This is different than `np.sort(temp)[::-1]` in that it places `nan`s at the back of the array instead of the front. Whether that's good or bad is up for debate..

Comment: I imagine which placing of`nan`s is best is dependant on the specific application. So it's good that there's a method for both, one may choose the best for their specific application.

Comment: This method did not work for me with a structured array, giving the error `numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'negative' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype([dtype list])`

Comment: short and sweet answer !! Should be the default answer to this question!

Comment: Note that this is (constant time) slower than the top/accepted answer since each minus sign is its own O(N) operation.

Answer (score 21):

For short arrays I suggest using `np.argsort()` by finding the indices of the sorted negatived array, which is slightly faster than reversing the sorted array:

```
In [37]: temp = np.random.randint(1,10, 10)

In [38]: %timeit np.sort(temp)[::-1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.65 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit temp[np.argsort(-temp)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.91 µs per loop
```

Comment: `a[np.argsort(-a)]` is probably the best approach to any others on this page. No -1 step reversal and one less minus sign to think about.

Answer (score 13):

`np.flip()` and reversed indexed are basically the same. Below is a benchmark using three different methods. It seems `np.flip()` is slightly faster. Using negation is slower because it is used twice so reversing the array is faster than that.

** Note that `np.flip()` is faster than `np.fliplr()` according to my tests.

```
def sort_reverse(x):
    return np.sort(x)[::-1]

def sort_negative(x):
    return -np.sort(-x)

def sort_flip(x):
    return np.flip(np.sort(x)) 

arr=np.random.randint(1,10000,size=(1,100000))

%timeit sort_reverse(arr)
%timeit sort_negative(arr)
%timeit sort_flip(arr)
```

and the results are:

```
6.61 ms ± 67.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
6.69 ms ± 64.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
6.57 ms ± 58.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Good to benchmark performance, thanks for your answer. I think this is the best, as this helps you choosing an approach. How does @Mazdak's answer do in this benchmark? Would be good to add `.argsort` as well

Comment: It is definitely slower (I tested it). However, I don't have my old machine to get the same values and compare them with the `argsort` method. On the other hand, these methods are more or less at the same speed, and the difference is noticeable if an extra large array is used. I myself use the standard python reversing method `[::1]` in my daily use if I deal with small arrays.

Answer (score 12):

## *Be careful with dimensions.*

#### Let

```py
x  # initial numpy array
I = np.argsort(x) or I = x.argsort() 
y = np.sort(x)    or y = x.sort()
z  # reverse sorted array
```

#### Full Reverse

```
z = x[I[::-1]]
z = -np.sort(-x)
z = np.flip(y)
```

- `flip` changed in [`1.15`](https://www.numpy.org/doc/1.15/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html?highlight=flip#numpy.flip), previous versions [`1.14`](https://www.numpy.org/doc/1.14/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html?highlight=flip#numpy.flip) *required* `axis`.  Solution: `pip install --upgrade numpy`.

#### First Dimension Reversed

```
z = y[::-1]
z = np.flipud(y)
z = np.flip(y, axis=0)
```

#### Second Dimension Reversed

```
z = y[::-1, :]
z = np.fliplr(y)
z = np.flip(y, axis=1)
```

## Testing

Testing on a 100×10×10 array 1000 times.

```
Method       | Time (ms)
-------------+----------
y[::-1]      | 0.126659  # only in first dimension
-np.sort(-x) | 0.133152
np.flip(y)   | 0.121711
x[I[::-1]]   | 4.611778

x.sort()     | 0.024961
x.argsort()  | 0.041830
np.flip(x)   | 0.002026
```

This is mainly due to reindexing rather than `argsort`.

```
# Timing code
import time
import numpy as np


def timeit(fun, xs):
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(len(xs)):  # inline and map gave much worse results for x[-I], 5*t
        fun(xs[i])
    t = time.time() - t
    print(np.round(t,6))

I, N = 1000, (100, 10, 10)
xs = np.random.rand(I,*N)
timeit(lambda x: np.sort(x)[::-1], xs)
timeit(lambda x: -np.sort(-x), xs)
timeit(lambda x: np.flip(x.sort()), xs)
timeit(lambda x: x[x.argsort()[::-1]], xs)
timeit(lambda x: x.sort(), xs)
timeit(lambda x: x.argsort(), xs)
timeit(lambda x: np.flip(x), xs)
```

Comment: np.flip() - super

Comment: I = np.argsort(x) and then z = x[-I] does not work when you have a zero in your x. By natural ordering it should go last, but it will go first in z since -0 == 0

Answer (score 10):

Hello I was searching for a solution to reverse sorting a two dimensional numpy array, and I couldn't find anything that worked, but I think I have stumbled on a solution which I am uploading just in case anyone is in the same boat.

```
x=np.sort(array)
y=np.fliplr(x)
```

`np.sort` sorts ascending which is not what you want, but the command `fliplr` flips the rows left to right!  Seems to work!

Hope it helps you out!

I guess it's similar to the suggest about `-np.sort(-a)` above but I was put off going for that by comment that it doesn't always work.  Perhaps my solution won't always work either however I have tested it with a few arrays and seems to be OK.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately when you have a complex array, only `np.sort(temp)[::-1]` works properly. The two other methods mentioned here are not effective.

Comment: @anishtain4: By "complex array", did you mean an array of complex numbers? Or did you mean an array with some other kind of complexity (if so pls specify what sort of complexity). In either case, I feel you could elaborate some more on your answer, by getting into how the other methods might fail. Thanks.

Comment: @fountainhead I mean the array of complex numbers. Since it's an old question I don't remember my test case from then to elaborate more.

Comment: @anishtain4 how do you even sort complex numbers? You cannot define ordering relations between complex numbers... you can only separately compare their real and imaginary parts, or their magnitudes.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the array first (Ascending by default) and then apply **np.flip()**
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html)

FYI It works with datetime objects as well.

Example:

```
    x = np.array([2,3,1,0]) 
    x_sort_asc=np.sort(x) 
    print(x_sort_asc)

    >>> array([0, 1, 2, 3])

    x_sort_desc=np.flip(x_sort_asc) 
    print(x_sort_desc)

    >>> array([3,2,1,0])
```

Comment: For those who have NaN in their arrays be careful, various proposed methods produce different results. For example if `x = np.array([2,3,np.nan,1,0]) ` then the `np.flip(np.sort(x))` approach yields [nan  3.  2.  1.  0.], while the `-np.sort(-x)` approach yields [ 3.  2.  1.  0. nan].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick trick

```
In[3]: import numpy as np
In[4]: temp = np.random.randint(1,10, 10)
In[5]: temp
Out[5]: array([5, 4, 2, 9, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 8])

In[6]: sorted = np.sort(temp)
In[7]: rsorted = list(reversed(sorted))
In[8]: sorted
Out[8]: array([2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9])

In[9]: rsorted
Out[9]: [9, 8, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sort` function from `numpy` :

```
array = np.random.rand(10) 
rev_sort = -np.sort(-array)
```

Answer (score -3):

i suggest using this ...

```
np.arange(start_index, end_index, intervals)[::-1]
```

for example:

```
np.arange(10, 20, 0.5)
np.arange(10, 20, 0.5)[::-1]
```

## Then your resault:

```
[ 19.5,  19. ,  18.5,  18. ,  17.5,  17. ,  16.5,  16. ,  15.5,
    15. ,  14.5,  14. ,  13.5,  13. ,  12.5,  12. ,  11.5,  11. ,
    10.5,  10. ]
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? You're just creating a completely, unrelated, new (descending) array which - by the way - could be done in a more efficient way: `np.arange(20-0.5, 10-0.5, -0.5)`. But that's a different story and may be, because of the worse readability, debatable. An input array is not sorted at all