# Pandas group: how to find the N largest values in multiple columns of each group?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I log a device and read 3 values (`W1`, `W2`, `W3`) every 15 minutes. They could be repeated.

I need to find **for every hour what are the max 3 values among the 12 that has been read** in that interval. I am not interested to know *when* they occurred, only their value.

At the moment my algorithm is far from being efficient and fast:

- Loop through each group:

  1. Transform W1, W2 and W3 to lists
  2. Combine the 3 lists together
  3. Sort the combined list
  4. Pick the largest elements.

**I would like to remove the loop** and use native pandas/numpy methods. Is it possible?

**EDIT: A working solution is been proposed at the end of this post**

This is the code:

```
from datetime import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

date_ref = datetime(2017,12,8,0,0,0)
days = pd.date_range(date_ref, date_ref + timedelta(0.11), freq='15min')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data1 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
data2 = data1 - np.random.randint(3, high=13, size=len(days))
data3 = data2 - np.random.randint(3, high=13, size=len(days))

df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': days, 'W1': data1, 'W2': data2, 'W3': data3 })
df = df.set_index('TIME')

print("Original data")
print("-------------")
print(df)
print("**********************************************")

# groupby
grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1H'))
print("Grouped data")
print("------------")
print list(grouped)
print("**********************************************")

print("3 largest values")
print("----------------")
for dtime, group in grouped:
    w  = list(group["W1"])
    w2 = list(group["W2"])
    w3 = list(group["W3"])
    w.extend(w2)
    w.extend(w3)
    w = sorted(w)

    max1 = w[-1]
    max2 = w[-2]
    max3 = w[-3]

    print(dtime, max1, max2, max3)
```

returns:

```
Original data
-------------
                     W1  W2  W3
TIME                           
2017-12-08 00:00:00  78  67  57
2017-12-08 00:15:00  73  64  59
2017-12-08 00:30:00  55  50  47
2017-12-08 00:45:00  67  58  51
2017-12-08 01:00:00  62  51  40
2017-12-08 01:15:00  52  40  32
2017-12-08 01:30:00  70  64  56
2017-12-08 01:45:00  74  67  63
2017-12-08 02:00:00  72  61  56
2017-12-08 02:15:00  70  58  55
2017-12-08 02:30:00  61  49  39
**********************************************
Grouped data
------------
[(Timestamp('2017-12-08 00:00:00', freq='H'),                      W1  W2  W3
TIME                           
2017-12-08 00:00:00  78  67  57
2017-12-08 00:15:00  73  64  59
2017-12-08 00:30:00  55  50  47
2017-12-08 00:45:00  67  58  51), (Timestamp('2017-12-08 01:00:00', freq='H'),                      W1  W2  W3
TIME                           
2017-12-08 01:00:00  62  51  40
2017-12-08 01:15:00  52  40  32
2017-12-08 01:30:00  70  64  56
2017-12-08 01:45:00  74  67  63), (Timestamp('2017-12-08 02:00:00', freq='H'),                      W1  W2  W3
TIME                           
2017-12-08 02:00:00  72  61  56
2017-12-08 02:15:00  70  58  55
2017-12-08 02:30:00  61  49  39)]
**********************************************
3 largest values
----------------
(Timestamp('2017-12-08 00:00:00', freq='H'), 78, 73, 67)
(Timestamp('2017-12-08 01:00:00', freq='H'), 74, 70, 67)
(Timestamp('2017-12-08 02:00:00', freq='H'), 72, 70, 61)
```

**SOLUTION**

I had some troubles implementing the solution in my code, so I leave here the final version for posterity. Perhaps it can be useful for somebody.

Even if @jezrael's solution works in my demo, it doesn't in my final version. It complains about a Timestamp that cannot be negated. It is pretty difficult to debug pandas groups, so I used @GeorgeLPerkins's. It is (to me) a lot easier to understand.

The biggest problem has been `grouped.apply()` that returns a series of list.

Extracting each element from each list is done using `str`: as the name suggest I thought it was involved with strings only and didn't consider it...

Now every direct loop is avoided, and the result `gdf` is a dataframe that can be saved into a database with a single write operation.

I am a newbie in pandas, alas, and I assume this can be highly optimized.

```
from datetime import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

date_ref = datetime(2017,12,8,0,0,0)
days = pd.date_range(date_ref, date_ref + timedelta(0.11), freq='15min')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data1 = np.random.randint(50, high=80, size=len(days))
data2 = data1 - np.random.randint(3, high=13, size=len(days))
data3 = data2 - np.random.randint(3, high=13, size=len(days))

df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': days, 'W1': data1, 'W2': data2, 'W3': data3 })
df = df.set_index('TIME')

#print("Original data")
#print("-------------")
#print(df)
#print("**********************************************")

# groupby
grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1H'))
print("Grouped data")
print("------------")
print list(grouped)
print("**********************************************")

print("3 largest values")
print("----------------")

def operation(x):
    combinedcoltop3 = []
    combinedcoltop3.extend(list(x.nlargest(3, "W1")["W1"])) # reads the 3 largest W1 and return W1 only
    combinedcoltop3.extend(list(x.nlargest(3, "W2")["W2"]))
    combinedcoltop3.extend(list(x.nlargest(3, "W3")["W3"]))
    combinedcoltop3.sort(reverse=True)
    return combinedcoltop3[:3]  # returns a list!

df1 = grouped.apply(operation) 

gdf = pd.DataFrame()
gdf["W1"] = df1.str[0]  # reads each element of the list for each row of df1
gdf["W2"] = df1.str[1]
gdf["W3"] = df1.str[2]

print(gdf)

# now gdf can be saved with a single write into the database
```

Comment: are you looking for this `df.resample('1H').max()`?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first flatenning all values to `1d` array by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), [sort it in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877045/2901002) and return top `3` values by indexing:

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1H')).apply(lambda x: -np.sort(-np.ravel(x))[:3])
print (df1)
TIME
2017-12-08 00:00:00    [78, 73, 67]
2017-12-08 01:00:00    [74, 70, 67]
2017-12-08 02:00:00    [72, 70, 61]
Freq: H, dtype: object
```

If want columns:

```
i = ['top1','top2','top3']
df1 = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1H'))
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(-np.sort(-np.ravel(x))[:3], index=i)))
print (df1)
                     top1  top2  top3
TIME                                 
2017-12-08 00:00:00    78    73    67
2017-12-08 01:00:00    74    70    67
2017-12-08 02:00:00    72    70    61
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! It workls perfectly, even if it is far above my knowledge to understand the why. I will go through it *slowly*

Answer (score 2):

What I find much simpler is:

```
combinedcoltop3 = []
for col in df.columns:
    combinedcoltop3.extend(list(df[col].nlargest(3)))

combinedcoltop3.sort(reverse=True)
top3 = combinedcoltop3[:3]
```

Comment: I am using a variation of your solution in my final code. 

I added the solution in my question. I had problems implementing jezrael's (it works in the demo here, but not in my code that uses a huge dataframe difficult to debug). 
Initially I didn't considered yours because it didn't work with groups but with dataframes only. For a newbie like me that has been confusing. Thank you very much for your help.