# Pandas: Rolling 2nd largest value

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I need to get the rolling 2nd largest value of a df.

To get the largest value I do

```
max = df.sort_index(ascending=True).rolling(10).max()
```

When I try this, python throws an error

```
max = df.sort_index(ascending=True).rolling(10).nlargest(2)

AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'nlargest'
```

Is this a bug? What else can I use that is performant?

Comment: Use `max = df.sort_index(ascending=True).rolling(10).apply(lambda x: x[-2])`

Comment: Dosen't this work only if the values are already sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [np.sort in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877045) and select second value:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': np.random.randint(20, size=15)
})
print (df)
     B
0    8
1   18
2    5
3   15
4   12
5   10
6   16
7   16
8    7
9    5
10  19
11  12
12  16
13  18
14   5
```

---

```
a = df.rolling(10).apply(lambda x: -np.sort(-x)[1]) 
#alternative
#a = df.rolling(10).apply(lambda x: np.sort(x)[-2]) 
print (a)
       B
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9   16.0
10  18.0
11  16.0
12  16.0
13  18.0
14  18.0
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd do something like this:

```
df.rolling(10).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).nlargest(2).iloc[-1])
```