# undefined solution for an Index Error message

Tags: python

i have this bloc of code that gives me an `IndexError`even if this part of the code is correct, but i don't know why, but i'm missing something that's for sure.

```py
mr = np.array([[0.3,0.2,0.4]])
permutation=np.argsort(mr)[::-1]
permutation
p0=mr[permutation]
p0
```

the traceback says i have the error in the `p0=mr[permutation]` and it gives me this error message: `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i want from this code is not having the biggest or the lowest value from the array i want to have the array in a sorted orderin a descending way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently sorting a numpy array in descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984414/efficiently-sorting-a-numpy-array-in-descending-order)

Comment: The dupe link have many answers. Please check.

Comment: thanks that is the winning answer that i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you try to use an Array as an index for a other Array.

So I think you want to have "p0" as the biggest value in "mr":

```
mr = np.array([[0.3,0.2,0.4]])
permutation=np.argsort(mr)[::-1]
permutation
p0=mr[0]
p0
```

or if you want it as the lowest than this:

```
mr = np.array([[0.3,0.2,0.4]])
permutation=np.argsort(mr)[::-1]
permutation
p0=mr[len(arr)-1]
p0
```

edit:

So this would be my solution to your porblem:

```
mr = np.array([0.3,0.2,0.4])
mr.sort()
mr = mr[::-1]
p0 = mr
```

Comment: no what i want from this code is not having the biggest or the lowest value from the array i want to have the array in a sorted orderin a descending way.

Comment: I would have added my solution to my original answer